# Magento - Four Products on Homepage - Random Order - Foreach Loop

Tags: magento

I'm trying to get 4 random products on the homepage using PHP within a TPL file I've created. I'd like to be able to format the products in a foreach loop as I'm using some formatting in the code seen below...

```
<div class="three columns">
  <div class="product_container no_border">
    <div class="product">
      <a href="product_page.html"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/products/place_holder.jpg'); ?>" alt=" "></a>
    </div>

    <div class="product_title">
      <a href="product_page.html">240 Serving Package</a>
    </div>

    <div class="price_hp">$454.99</div>

    <div class="free_shipping">
      <div class="fs"></div>
      Free shipping for this package
    </div>

    <div class="shop_btn">
      <a href="#">ADD TO CART</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know what PHP to use though to grab the 4 products from any category and randomize the order. May I have some guidance please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following code in your phtml file for randomize products..

```
$categoryid = 15;
$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($categoryid);
$products = $category->getProductCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$products->getSelect()->order('RAND()');
$products->getSelect()->limit(4);
foreach($products as $prod)
{
  echo $prod->getName() ."<br>";
  $img=$prod->getSmallImageUrl();
  echo "<img src='$img'>" ."<br>";
}
```